# Handling invalid query parameters in mule

Tags: mule

I am trying to figure out a way to handle invalid query parameters which is not defined in my api.raml. What are the best practices for handling invalid query parameters in mule?

Thanks
Joel

Comment: What is an invalid query param for you ? 

- A query param that should be provided but contains a wrong format / value ?

- A query param that shouldn't be provided ?

Comment: @mario martinez Invalid param would be like a query param that shouldn't be provided.